# Overriding description method for class which is containing objects from another class

Tags: objective-c, class, inheritance

I am confused in making a class to identify itself when it contains few objects from another class.

Let say :

I have 2 Classes and 1 subClass :

a. Stock

b. ForeignStock (subClass of Stock)

c. StockHolding

For Stock and ForeignStock, I have overridden description method, so those 2 can describe itself when I put their objects into an Array, and NSLogged contents of array.

Description for Stock Class

```
-(NSString *)description{

    NSString *objectDescriptionFormat = @"\n" "========= Properties of Stock Value %@ ==========\n"
    "Purchase price is %f\n" "Current Price is %f\n" "Number of Shares bought is %i\n" "\n"
    "------------------- Total Value & Cost ------------------\n"
    "Value in dollar for this stock is %f\n" "Cost in dollar for this stock is %f\n" "\n";

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:objectDescriptionFormat, 
    [super description],self.purchaseSharePrice,self.currentSharePrice,
    self.numberOfShares,
    self.valueInDollars,self.costInDollars];
}
```

Description for ForeignStock Class

```
 -(NSString *)description
 {
     NSString *objectDescriptionFormat = @"%@" "Conversion rate for this stock is %f\n"  "\n" ;

     return [NSString stringWithFormat: objectDescriptionFormat,[super description],self.conversionRate];
 }
```

I put objects created from Stock & ForeignStock Class inside an instance of StockHolding,but here are some problems :

1. How do I display objects inside StockHolding? (I put an array as property of StockHolding)
2. Do I have to create 2 method inside StockHolding to addObject from Stock & ForeignStock Class? or 1 addObject method is enough?
3. as you can see from description methods above, Stock & ForeignStock have different values
   How do I setup calculationValue to count each value of stock stored inside StockHolding?

note: I created custom accessors

```
@interface Portfolio : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray  *_portfolioStocks;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSArray *portfolioStocks;

-(NSArray *)portfolioStocks{
    return  [_portfolioStocks copy];
}

-(void)setPortfolioStocks:(NSArray *)portfolioStocks{

    _portfolioStocks = [portfolioStocks mutableCopy];
}

- (void)addStocks: (StockHolding *) newStocks{

    // is portfolio array nil?
    if (!_portfolioStocks) {
        //create array
        _portfolioStocks = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    [_portfolioStocks addObject:newStocks];
}
```

Comment: You are asking three different and separate questions. Keep each post to one question.

Comment: Don't use `description` for anything but debugging purposes.  It should never be used as a part of program output.